# Architecture for white-label mobile apps with React Native

Tags: react-native, architecture, hybrid-mobile-app

We have a mobile application that we scale as the white label, so we develop and release more and more mobile apps with similar features.

We are faced with the fact that we need more and more effort to support applications. Application functionality may differ slightly, i.e. they are not identical.

How can you “assemble” applications from modules to spend a minimum of time on support? We now have one repository, and each project has a separate branch. It becomes a nightmare to move features across branches (the functionality is 70% similar, but there are differences, so we can’t just apply new colors, logo, images and release).

Advise on what approach to development and scaling to take. We are thinking towards a mono repository.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple answer to this question. Think of how **Tailwind** or **Nativewind** works, take a look at **atomic design patterns**, and build a **UI layer** where React and React-Native are kings, only components/screens.

Separate the logic into a **dedicated layer**, let's call it **domain** **(check Clean Architecture)**. **Use dependency injection** -> Let's call a piece of your logic with the term **use-case**.

Now imagine if you have a pure **UI layer** that gets injected via props with **different use-cases**. In that way, your **UI layer** can stay out of your different application's logic, and it can **globally change its fonts/colors/dimensions**.

On a different layer, you can build the logic this app needs **(Factory pattern is particularly useful in this scenario)**.

It might sound confusing but it is not an easy task to build apps like a conveyor machine.